# How can I automatically trigger a terraform destroy in aws if the infrastructure has not been used for a certain time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch

I want my infrastructure to be destroyed automatically if it has not been used for a certain amount of time, eg. 1 hour.

I am using S3 backend for terraform meaning I can apply or destroy from anywhere. I'm wondering if a good solution is to create an cloudwatch metric in my terraform script for the load balancer created. Then create a lambda function which keep checking this metric and do a terraform destroy if the load balancer has not had any incoming data for an hour?

Answer (score 0):

> create a lambda function which keep checking this metric and do a terraform destroy if the load balancer has not had any incoming data for an hour?

Yes, you can do that. The point is that AWS does not monitor your usage, except few cases in [AWS Trusted Advisor](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/technology/trusted-advisor/) which can detect not-utilized instances or load balancers.

So you would have to develop your own solution for that, and lambda with cloudwatch is a good way of doing this. Off course the issue is, how would you start the balancer later on when you get the metrics. Without LB, there won't be any new metrics generated to indicate that you have new requests.

Comment: can't you create metrics in aws cloudwatch? So I could create the metric with a particular name inside the terraform so that it monitors the usage (eg network pakcets in) of the load balancer which is created at the same time, and then in lambda I can write a function which will look for this metric and, if it exists, then keep checking it if it exists to see if no network packets have come in over the last hour and then do a destroy.

Comment: @JonnyShanahan If you terminate your LB, metrics won't be generated. So you will not know if there is any incoming traffic.

Comment: @Macin but I will only terminate after it has been detected through the metric that it hasn't been used for a while. And then on the next apply a new metric will be generated with the same name, (meaning that the code in the lambda function can search for this name to find the metric each time). I'm not 100% that it will work, but this is my plan